# Weighted subset sum problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Given an integer sequence $\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N  \}$ that has length $N$ and a fixed integer $M\leq N$, the [problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/public/WEIGHTED-SUM.pdf) is to find a subset $A =\{i_1, \dots, i_M\} \subseteq [N]$ with $1 \leq i_1 \lt i_1 \lt \dots \lt i_M \leq N$ such that

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^M j \cdot a_{i_j}$

is maximized.

---

For instance, if the given sequence is $-50; 100; -20; 40; 30$ and $M = 2$, the best weighted sum arises when we choose positions 2 and 4.

So that we get a value $1 \cdot 100 + 2 \cdot 40 = 180$.

On the other hand, if the given sequence is $10; 50; 20$ and $M$ is again 2, the best option is to choose positions 1 and 2 that we get a value $1 \cdot 10 + 2 \cdot 50 = 110$.

---

To me it looks similar to the [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), but I can think of many examples in which the maximum subarray is not the best solution.

Is this problem an instance of a well studied problem? What is the best algorithm to solve it?

This question was inspired by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861642/find-maximum-weighted-sum-over-all-m-subsequences).

Comment: What constraints are imposed on the sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$?

Comment: It is an integer sequence, there aren't particular constraints. Why?

Comment: I do not understand your example 1. Should not that be $2 \cdot 100 + 4 \cdot 40$? And example 2 be $2 \cdot 50 + 3 \cdot 20$?

Comment: Your examples do not appear to match the sum you have defined...

Comment: The correct formulation is [here](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/public/WEIGHTED-SUM.pdf)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Sorry, the examples were right the formula was wrong

Comment: In your example, $50;100;20;40;30$ why can't I choose $50;100$, which would give me $1 \times 50 + 2 \times 100 = 250$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That they are integers is sufficient (that is a constraint in itself).

Comment: Your summation (in revision 3) in condition 2 does not make sense.  Why don’t you write exactly as defined in the PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved by means of dynamic programming. One of the best known dynamic programming algorithms is for the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It may be instructive to compare the two problems.

Let $C(n,m)$ denote the solution to the maximal weighted sum problem
for the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$ with a subsequence of length $m$ where $1\leq n\leq N$ and $1\leq m\leq M$.

Then $C(n,m+1) = \mathop{max}(C(n-1,m+1), C(n-1,m) + (m+1) \cdot a_n)$.

To compute $C(N,M)$ this algorithm can be implemented in $O(N M)$ time and $O(N)$ space.

Comment: Note that if you want to obtain $A$, you need $\Theta(NM)$ space, too; you have to keep all computed values plus predecessor information for backtracking (or, alternatively, paths of length $\Theta(N)$ in each of the $\Theta(N)$ maintained values).